# Docker ftp client - active connection not working

Tags: networking, ftp, docker

Connecting to ftp via active connection on my host machine works fine. Doing it in a docker container doesn't. Passive works fine on both but i need to support both connection types.

I found this simple image that can be used to illustrate the [issue](https://hub.docker.com/r/dockito/ftp-client/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated)

**Host**

[image]

**Container** (includes slightly older version of ftp that defaults to active mode)

[image]

My question is can anybody else successfully connect via active connection using that image? I don't believe the server is the issue as like i said this works fine on host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to read about the differences of active and passive mode ftp:
[What is the difference between active and passive FTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699145/what-is-the-difference-between-active-and-passive-ftp)

You can see that active mode ftp is not suited for containerized ftp clients,
due to the server actively trying to initiate a data connection
to the ftp client, which is not possible for a container.

With passive mode ftp on the other hand, the server will tell your ftp client which port needs to be used for the next data connection.

**Linux method**

The simple way to use active ftp in a container is to
use `network: host`, which may have unwanted effects:

```
docker run [other flags] --network host <image_name>
```

For more information, see Docker documentation
[Networking overview](https://docs.docker.com/network/).

This method works perfectly well on Linux, but not on Windows.
Below is how to do it in Windows.

**Windows method**

This method was found in the post
[Bridge with Docker for Windows](https://forums.docker.com/t/bridge-with-docker-for-windows/30936/5) .

First, create a custom network on Docker. Example:

```
docker network create -d bridge --subnet 172.168.0.0/16 mynet
```

Unlike Linux, where the new network is automatically bridged to the NIC,
this is not possible in Windows, because Hyper-V doesn’t offer
Bridged option for Linux containers.

In Windows, to set a container to respond from your custom network and
using a custom IP, this specific IP address must exist in the
*Docker Network Adapter*, commonly named as `vEthernet (DockerNAT)`.
Here is how:

1. Go to *Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections*
2. Right-click `vEthernet (DockerNAT)` and select Properties
3. Select `Internet Protocol Version 4(TCP/IPv4)` and click Properties
4. Give the adapter a static IP address that is valid on the real network.
   Ensure the DNS is also valid for the container to resolve domains on the web
   5, Click Advanced, then Add, then enter the IP to include in the list.
   The Subnet mask should auto-fill automatically
   (but can be changed if needed).
   Repeat for every IP you intend to use, for as many as you need,
   from the same or different networks.

Once you complete this step, the custom network is ready to use.

The article gives an example:

> As an example, try installing the Portainer to run from your custom
> network. Here’s how:
>
> First, create the require Portainer volume (step only needed on
> Windows):
>
> ```
> docker volume create portainer_data
> ```
>
> Then create the Portainer container using:
>
> ```
> docker run -d -p 9000:9000 --name portainer --network mynet --ip 172.168.0.254 --restart always -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v portainer_data:/data
> ```
>
> portainer/portainer
>
> Noticed the keywords `--network` and `--ip`? You can even set a custom
> local domain (for instance, docker.local) in the hosts file that
> points to the IP address 172.168.0.254 which will allow you to access
> the local Portainer via http://docker.local:9000 (or
> http://172.168.0.254:9000).

**Mac method**

According to Docker documentation article
[Use host networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/):

> The host networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not
> supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows, or
> Docker EE for Windows Server.
>
> You can also use a `host` network for a swarm service, by passing
> `--network host` to the `docker service create` command. In this case,
> control traffic (traffic related to managing the swarm and the
> service) is still sent across an overlay network, but the individual
> swarm service containers send data using the Docker daemon’s host
> network and ports. This creates some extra limitations. For instance,
> if a service container binds to port 80, only one service container
> can run on a given swarm node.

See also the post
[Accessing host machine from within docker container](https://forums.docker.com/t/accessing-host-machine-from-within-docker-container/14248).

Comment: Fully aware of the differences between active/passive. Looks like that flag is only supported on docker for linux which is a shame.

Comment: I have expanded my answer for Windows.

Comment: Well you might guess my next question, what about mac?

Comment: You got me on this one. Perhaps one of the above is adaptable to MacOS.

Comment: Hey @harrymc, the answer isn't quite complete as i couldn't get it to work on the mac (which is what i use day to day). I'll upvote your answer though and if someone else does the same i believe you get half the bounty.

Comment: According to [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/): "You can also use a `host` network for a swarm service, by passing `--network host` to the `docker service create` command". That might be the way to go, but read more in the link. See also [this post](https://forums.docker.com/t/accessing-host-machine-from-within-docker-container/14248).

Comment: Yano what harry, you've been so helpful (and i don't have enough rep to upvote embarrassingly) i'm gonna give you the bounty. Thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks, and here's 10 rep back to you.